# What is `implementation` configuration of gradle java plugin?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm a newbie for Gradle, and now learning about configuration. Many developers use the `implementation` configuration in their `build.gradle` , but I don't understand what it is for.

I'm reading [gradle document](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management) and found that configuration is provided by java plugin. But the description is not easy yet for me.

> implementation extends compile
> Implementation only dependencies.

What does "implementation only" in this term means?